# My HTML Element Has a Chinese Title. Can jQuery Help Me Render the Tooltip Correctly in the Browser?

Tags: jquery, unicode, character-encoding, cross-browser, tooltip

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="www.cnn.com" title="甲骨文">A link with a Chinese title</a>
</body>
</html>
```

- If you hover over the link in Firefox, the Chinese characters are correctly displayed in the tooltip.
- However, if you hover over the link in IE8, Google Chrome, or Safari, three blocks are displayed.

My Question:

> Can jQuery help me override the default browser 'title' tooltip behavior and correctly display the Chinese characters?

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7j5cE/ (if someone wants to see the behavior live)

Comment: You can use a jQuery tooltip plug-in...

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Which plugin? I don't seem to be any better off with this one (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/).

Comment: There are many tooltip plug-ins out there: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Comment: My Chrome displays the tooltip properly. (Chrome 8 on Debian/SID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many JavaScript-tooltip scripts available, as jQuery plugins or otherwise. They are typically meant for including images or other hypertextual content, but would have the side-effect of using browser fonts instead of the OS UI font for tooltips in IE.

However, I wouldn't resort to JavaScript tooltips just for that. The desktop of a Chinese user will certainly have a working Chinese OS font installed so the tooltip will work fine there. If it does not, it is quite unlikely that there will be a Chinese font available to browser document content. Especially on IE, which traditionally has a poorer browser-font-fallback mechanism than Firefox. (Can IE even render in-page Chinese content on your machine?)

Comment: Thanks @bobince, you are right. To fix this problem on a Windows XP machine, right-click on the desktop, then go to Properties > [Appearance Tab] > Advanced > Item[Tooltip] > and change the font to 'Arial Unicode MS' (or some other unicode-supporting font). Everything should work now.

Comment: Yeah, Arial Unicode is OK as a last ditch effort if you haven't got a real Chinese/whatever-language font, but although it has a lot of glyphs it is missing other language-sensitive features which tend to make it a substandard choice. This is why it's typically not used as fallback. If you want Chinese tooltips, best install the standard East Asian fonts (from the Regional and Language Options control panel).

Comment: @JimG i think you could add ur comment as an optional answer!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem on a Windows XP machine, right-click on the desktop, then go to Properties > [Appearance Tab] > Advanced > Item[Tooltip] > and change the font to 'Arial Unicode MS' (or some other unicode-supporting font).

Everything should work now.